# Setting up local git server and adding multiple users

Tags: git, github, repository, bitbucket

I am successful in creating a local git repository and cloning it to another folder.

What I am not able to do is pushing files from the cloned folder to the repository.

And I want my team mates to use the same repository and pull & push the codes.

Thank you

Comment: So, what happens if you try? And the part about team-mates, what happened there?

Comment: Please write us more about where those repositiories are? It may be directory user right only, or something other,

Comment: Git does not come with any access management, so there is no concept of users or permissions. Please read a book on how Git on a server works, and what you can do if you want any kind of access management.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all read this: [Setting-Up-the-Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server).

You will also need to set up **transfer protocols** for git.
Read about it here and choose the right protocol for you.

> #### The Protocols
>
> Git can use four major protocols to transfer data:
>
> Local, `HTTP`, Secure Shell (`SSH`) and `Git`.
> Here we’ll discuss what they are and in what basic circumstances you would want (or not want) to use them.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

Comment: I have read those contents and then I came here for the question. I didn't understand what its said there. Can you please provide me some simple codes to setup a local git repository server and then make my friends from their computer to pull and push files?

Comment: In order to connect git you need a protocol. like when you open browser - you use http/https. the same apply to git, you need to set a communication protocol